Who is William Bigelow Easton?
William Bigelow Easton is the full name of the American mathematician who is the eponym of Easton's theorem, a far-reaching application of the method of forcing in set theory.
Despite the many citations of this celebrated result, I can't find much information about the man. The extent of what I know can be found in the German Wikipedia, which attests to the paucity of his publications, and mentions that he taught computer science at Rutgers in the early 70's. He earned his PhD at Princeton in 1964, under the supervision of Alonzo Church.
I can't determine from Google any other details of his life, such as the year of his birth or whether he's still alive. Is any of this recorded somewhere?

My personal records have that he was born in 1939, and using that, a google search for "William Bigelow Easton" + 1939 may lead to additional information. Some of the search methods I discuss in my answer to Who is Donald L. Webb will likely be useful.

Thank you, Dave (+1). Your search methods are good to know.

In case it could be of help (now or with something else later), I just realized that I had overlooked another answer of mine in which various internet search tips are given: Who was N.M. Stephens who refuted the Stronger Feit-Thompson Conjecture?

I like these things as a private investigator. When I was young, I used to watch Magnum, P.I. (I'll explain why later).
William Bigelow Easton, born in Norfolk, Virginia (USA) on March 8, 1939 to William Thomas Easton and Helen "Manoa" Bigelow; he is currently still alive and resides in Charlottesville, Virginia.
In gathering information, I couldn't help but notice similarities with the hero of my youth, Thomas Sullivan Magnum IV, who lived in Virginia and was the son of a naval officer.

Thank you!  Not to deprive you of credit, but I also discovered this myself after the lead provided by Dave Renfro, and from what I can tell poking around, Dr. Easton seems to be a lovely gentleman. :-)

@ToddTrimble You're welcome! Not to take away credit from Dave Renfro, but I had already found the relevant data before reading his comment; I wrote the response anyway, both for the "officiality" and to joke about Thomas Magnum.

Great!  Do you have any tips to share for how you got this?  (I guess some P.I.s might like to keep their methods P.)

William "Bill" Bigelow Easton is my father in law.  He is a stellar human being and a really good guy.  On top of being a genius mathematician, he has an amazing voice and sang for decades with multiple choirs.  The amazing stories that he can tell you about people that he knows and the things that he has done are endless.  Bill has traveled to Haiti numerous times to install solar and generators medical at hospitals and clinics from Cap Haitian to Jacmel.

Thank you! I'm glad to learn of this.
